# Does subpixel rendering require low-level access to hardware?

Tags: graphics, rendering

Does [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering), like with Microsoft's Clear Type, require some sort of low-level access to the monitor hardware? It's not clear to me how these "subpixels" are activated.
If it does require lower level access than other imagery, does that also mean that you can't make a screenshot of it? I mean, of course you could make a screenshot of it, but perhaps the subpixel rendering is (partially) lost in doing so, since the screenshot uses full pixels?

This question got to me after reading this one: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/930/why-does-anti-aliasing-in-black-characters-use-colors-other-than-gray-scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it just requires some information (possibly guesswork) about how R/G/B values map to the displayed pixels. You certainly can take screenshots of it.